# Invoking another xml file in same program :android

Tags: android

```
public class AndroidCamera extends Activity implements  SurfaceHolder.Callback{

Camera camera;
SurfaceView surfaceView;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
boolean previewing = false;;
PictureCallback rawCallback;
ShutterCallback shutterCallback;
PictureCallback jpegCallback;
private Bitmap bitmap;
TextView colorRGB;
Config config;
String callname;
String callnamePimage;
String callnameRimage;
String name = null;


EditText txtData, Info,Age;

ImageView imageView = null;
ImageView imageView2 = null;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

   Button buttonStartCameraPreview = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startcamerapreview);
   Button buttonStopCameraPreview = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopcamerapreview);
   Button buttonCapturePreview = (Button) findViewById(R.id.capturepreview);
   Button testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testButton); 


    txtData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Info = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
    Info.setHint("enter name");
    Age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Age);
    Age.setHint("Age");



    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);


   imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

   imageView2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);


    rawCallback = new PictureCallback() 
    {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
        {
            Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - raw");
        }
    };

    shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback()
    {
        public void onShutter() {
            Log.i("Log", "onShutter'd");
        }
    };

    jpegCallback = new PictureCallback()
    {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) 
         {

            Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/Raw Image");
            imagesFolder.mkdirs(); 
            Date d = new Date();
            CharSequence s  = DateFormat.format("MM-dd-yy hh-mm-ss", d.getTime());
            name = s.toString() + ".jpg";              
              File output = new File(imagesFolder, name);


            Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(output);
            imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);

            OutputStream imageFileOS;

            try {
                imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriSavedImage);
                imageFileOS.write(data);
                imageFileOS.flush();
                imageFileOS.close();

                Toast.makeText(AndroidCamera.this, 
                        "Image saved: ", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
                {
                e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            finally
            {}
            Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - jpeg");

            callname = "/sdcard/Raw Image/" + name;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(callname);

            //imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);//Displaying raw Image
             displayimages();
  }
  }  


    buttonStartCameraPreview.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
    {

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if(!previewing)
            {
                camera = Camera.open(0);
                if (camera != null)
                {

                    try {

                        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                        camera.startPreview();
                        previewing = true;
                        } 
                    catch (IOException e) 
                        {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }else txtData.setText("null");
            }
        }});



    buttonCapturePreview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
   {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

            captureImage();
        }


    });


    buttonStopCameraPreview.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

            if(camera != null && previewing)
            {
                camera.stopPreview();
                camera.release();
                camera = null;

                previewing = false;
            }
        }});


}

private void captureImage() 
{
    camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);

}

private void displayimages()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            setContentView(R.layout.display);
    callnameRimage = "/sdcard/Raw Image/" + name;
    Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(callnameRimage);
    imageView2.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);


}
```

i have used an xml file called "main" which have surface view and some button. In this i have saved an image to a folder called Raw Image. I need to decode this image into a image view which is in another xml file called "display." when i executed the program gets crashed. I have added the code...Please help me by pointing out where am going wrong.

log cat error

```
12-12 10:40:48.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 10:40:48.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-12 10:40:48.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at com.example.imaging.AndroidCamera.displayimages(AndroidCamera.java:397)
12-12 10:40:48.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at com.example.imaging.AndroidCamera.access$0(AndroidCamera.java:390)
12-12 10:40:48.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at com.example.imaging.AndroidCamera$3.onPictureTaken(AndroidCamera.java:313)
12-12 10:40:48.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:687)
12-12 10:40:48.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-12 10:40:48.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-12 10:40:48.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-12 10:40:48.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 10:40:48.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-12 10:40:48.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-12 10:40:48.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-12 10:40:48.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Where is your crash report ?

Comment: i have added the logcat error please tell me where am goin wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your below your `ImageView` is null as you have inflated another layout and you did not initialized the `ImageView` after that and directly you are setting the image on it. Just initialize your `ImageView` as below:

```
private void displayimages()
{
    setContentView(R.layout.display);
    callnameRimage = "/sdcard/Raw Image/" + name;
    Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(callnameRimage);
    imageView2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2); //Initialize this way
    imageView2.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
}
```

Initialize your `imageView2` in this method not in `onCreate()` because you are trying to access it in this method after inflating the `display` layout. And as it resides in `display` only not in your `main` layout file.

Comment: I have updated my code...dat line was there in my code...it was deleted by mistake when i pasted here. still the code is not working

Comment: Ok fine tell me one thing does your `ImageView` resides in your `main` layout file or in `display` layout file ?

Comment: If its in `display` layout file then surely you will get the error as you are trying to get it from your `main` layout file in your `onCreate` method.

Comment: so can you give me the solution

Comment: I have already answered your solution in my answer. Remove the `imageView2` declaration from your `onCreate()` method and initalize it in `displayimages()` method as i have shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void displayimages()
    {

    setContentView(R.layout.display);
    callnameRimage = "/sdcard/Raw Image/" + name;
    Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(callnameRimage);
    imageView2= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2Id);
    imageView2.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);


    }
```

Where `imageView2Id` is the ID `imageView2` in `display` layout,